# JSON only loading once in IE7 & 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm calling in a JSON file when a user clicks a button, it loads the first time, but when you refresh the page it fails, what could be wrong? This problem happens in IE7 and IE8, its' fine in other browsers.

```
$(document).on('click', '.game-reg-button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
           loadContent(); 
       });


 function loadContent(){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/content.json",
            data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(source){
                data = source;
                showStartpage(data);
                showInfo(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("Failed to load content");
            }
        }); 

    }
```

Comment: with _refresh_, you mean a reload of the whole page with the browsers reload button?

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?  What happens?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: NOTE: The `contentType` option is the `Content-type` header sent ***to*** the server in the ***request***!  It is *not* the `Content-type` of the *response*.  It is incorrect here.

Comment: no errors occur, but when I click it fails to load and just shows the loading image I have instead

Comment: yes a reload of the whole page with the browsers reload button

Comment: Does it alert "Failed to load content"? that would be a more direct way of expressing how it failed.

Comment: it is hard to guess without additional code or information what _fails_ means. but it sounds like you either load script with e.g. `$.getScript` or that you use a `.load` instead of `.ready` to setup you event handlers. you should check if the code part that setups `$(document).on('click', '.game-reg-button'` is called.